# Set different locale in terminals and KDE

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, kde, locale

#### My environment

I'm using ArchLinux with KDE.

#### What I'd like to do

What I would like is to have KDE in my language (`fr_FR`) but all the terminals and tty in `en_US` (for debugging and having the same error messages as the community).

Is it possible?

#### What I'm currently doing

For now, I set the locale in `locale.conf` to `fr_FR.UTF-8`, in order to have the DM in french.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally put

```
LANG = "en_US.UTF8"
```

in my `~/.bashrc` and for all the users that I would log in with...

And in `/etc/locale.conf`, I chose my DM language.

IMO it's not really pretty, but it works.